# The three point beverage

Tags: word

[Please feel free to provide any constructive criticism and feedback on how long it took to solve this and what your thoughts are as I'm new to puzzling and I'd like to improve.]

[image]

Comment: Remember to accept the correct answer; you can do that now. ;-)

Comment: Wound up here after finding [this card](https://photos.app.goo.gl/qGUS6HJWqL1JxYHv7) as part of a [lockbox puzzle](https://www.lockboxadventures.com/) I was given.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I see

> Chuck Brown Ale

Because

> Next letter for each word on the adjacent (clockwise) vertex in the following triangle. Starting with C, C -> H -> U -> C -> K. The other two words are constructed similarly.

Comment: Well done. I was hoping it would take slightly longer to solve this haha. I was hoping it would take at least 5-10 minutes for a "normal" audience. [granted I have no idea how often you do puzzles].

Comment: @leigero The blanks on the last two were a big hint which lead me to think it was more than one word, one ending with -CK, another with -WN because -CN is not very likely. I worked backwards from there. A puzzle solved quickly isn't necessarily a bad puzzle.

Comment: @leigero There are a lot of *excellent* puzzle solvers that frequent this site.  Just because your puzzle is solved quickly, does *not* make it a bad puzzle.  (See [The many-eyes effect](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/the-many-eyes-effect).) I actually think this was a great puzzle, and more creative than a lot of the first-time puzzles we get.

Comment: Change rot13(nyr) to rot13(yntre) to fill in those last two squares, and it might be a bit harder.  (No idea if that's a real drink or not...)

Comment: @leigero For geometrical twist on your puzzle, roll your puzzle up into a hexagon with a missing pie slice.  Then insert a blank pie slice.

Comment: @Yakk I actually have a hexagon version I created with other symbols haha.